# Elasticsearch Snapshot failed - Cannot Restore

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, aws-elasticsearch

I'm trying to move data from one instance to another elasticsearch instance. I've created the Roles and s3 bucket as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html).

I've registered the repository in both instances, the snapshot created successfully, and s3 has new objects. but when I run the restore command. I'm getting an error as follows

```
:[{"type":"snapshot_restore_exception","reason":"[test:sample5/xcMBVd21SQky8E2TX8Z76xf] index [example] wasn't fully snapshotted - cannot restore"}]
```

I created a snapshot using python script,

```
path = '_snapshot/test/' + sampe_snap
url = host + path
payload = {
  "indices": "example",
  "include_global_state": False
}

r = requests.put(url, json=payload, auth=awsauth)
```

which returns

```
{"accepted":true}
```

In order to debug, I've used Kibana and searched for the snapshot. It shows as follows

```
GET _snapshot/test/sampe_snap
    ....
    "indices" : [ "example" ],
    "include_global_state" : false,
    "state" : "PARTIAL",
    "start_time" : "2021-02-04T11:14:22.153Z",
    "start_time_in_millis" : 1612437262153,
    "end_time" : "2021-02-04T11:14:22.554Z",
    "end_time_in_millis" : 1612437262554,
    "duration_in_millis" : 401,
    "failures" : [ {
      "index" : "example",
      "index_uuid" : "example",
      "shard_id" : 3,
      "reason" : """java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: Blob object [indices/TJz0FNoGQUfvJ5pbTFLyQ/3/index-f16nCDQoiRl4UV8vCFSA] not found: The specified key does not exist.
    (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey...;
```

Why is it failing?

Comment: Well the error message is pretty clear: `index [example] wasn't fully snapshotted - cannot restore` which means that the index you're trying to restore wasn't completely snapshotted, so it can't be restored

Comment: @Val I've updated the question please have a look

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear:

> index [example] wasn't fully snapshotted - cannot restore

which means that the index you're trying to restore wasn't completely snapshotted, so it can't be restored.

As you can see from the snapshot details, it has a [state `PARTIAL`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-restore-snapshot.html#_partial_restore), which means that not all shards of the index could be snapshotted successfully. In your case, the shard #3 of the `example` index wasn't successfully snapshotted, and hence, the segments of that shard (i.e. `index-f16nCDQoiRl4UV8vCFSA`) cannot be found in the S3 bucket, hence the index cannot be restored.

You can try to restore that partial snapshot by setting `partial: true`, but all missing shards with be empty, so you might lack some data.

Maybe try another snapshot that was created earlier or later.

Comment: in my case every time, even with a single index, snapshot creation fails.
"shards" : {
      "total" : 5,
      "failed" : 5,
      "successful" : 0
    }

Comment: When I search for snapshots
```
GET _snapshot/test/_all

It returns error as, 
 "type" : "snapshot_missing_exception",
  "reason" : "[mgtm-test:my-snapshot/Q0TyEey_TNuiF_50SQ1glA] is missing"

Comment: Can you share what you see in your ES server logs when the snapshot is being created?

Comment: I'm not getting any error logs. only some warning.

[2021-02-04T05:16:10,825][WARN ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [3ee47ae36b7028746301af48aa83f3ca] cluster state applier task [ApplyCommitRequest{term=88, version=796619, sourceNode={ba4d072d2a8c63b60e1832f0109c2ac4}{kx7DSpLOToWNxLzEFm8N1g}{l6ruGMsiQ_yCZDr4er4c2g}{__IP__}{__IP__}{dimr}{__AMAZON_INTERNAL__, __AMAZON_INTERNAL__, distributed_snapshot_deletion_enabled=true}}] took [38s] which is above the warn threshold of [30s]:

Comment: Can you update your question instead, it's more legible

Comment: Hi, ValThanks for your time. When I tried creating snapshot for a newly created index in the cluster it worked. The issue is with old indices residing in the cluster (which were upgraded from 6.8 to 7.7 )

Answer (score 1):

Here the problem is that snapshot is ending in `PARTIAL` state instead of `SUCCESS` state.

The reason for snapshot to end in PARTIAL state is that because of some issue in S3 repository `index-f16nCDQoiRl4UV8vCFSA` file inside `shard 3` of index `TJz0FNoGQUfvJ5pbTFLyQ` (snapshot index id of index `example`) is missing. Which is clear case of **repository corruption**.

```
  "reason" : """java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: Blob object [indices/TJz0FNoGQUfvJ5pbTFLyQ/3/index-f16nCDQoiRl4UV8vCFSA] not found: The specified key does not exist.
```

This kind of repository corruption is observed when cluster is heavily loaded (JVM > 80% or CPU utilization >80%) and few of nodes drops out of cluster.

One way to fix the issue is to delete all the snapshots that refers to index :`example`. This will cleanup S3 snapshot files of index `example` and now when you take new snapshot everything starts afresh.

To be on safer side, I would recommend to contact AWS support to fix this type of repository corruption.